# is there a way where I can call an network API call on main thread in android honeycomb?

Tags: android, api, thread-safety, android-3.0-honeycomb, background-process

I am creating a service and an app. App can call a method on a service. The method is calling an API and based on API, giving the result. Since the app is targetting android 3.0, I am getting "NetworkOnMainThreadException".

My requirement is such a way that I cannot call the method in background thread from app. Also the method on service should return a boolean based on API call.

is there a way where I can call an network API call on main thread in android honeycomb?

Comment: call it on a separate thread.

Comment: Exactly - the constraint of not being able to use an additional thread is a false one.  If it's a "rule of practice" it's coming from someone unaware that an android process already requires a number of background threads to communicate with the android runtime.

Answer (score 30):

```
import android.os.StrictMode;

StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: Finally someone who doesn't argue about crap and just gives the answer. . i like your style +1 from me :)

Comment: the same here no arguing about crap a +1 and even a kiss

Comment: After doing this, how can we set the thread policy to default again?

Answer (score 7):

> I am creating a service and an app.

A service is a part of an "app". I am going to assume that you meant "activity" where you wrote "app".

> My requirement is such a way that I cannot call the method in background thread from app.

Then whoever created this "requirement" is an idiot and should be fired. Then, remove this requirement. Always perform network operations on a background thread.

> Since the app is targetting android 3.0, I am getting "NetworkOnMainThreadException".

That is because `StrictMode` is on to warn you about these things by default. While the warning is new, the problem exists on all versions of Android your code is running on.

> is there a way where I can call an network API call on main thread in android honeycomb?

This should never be done in production code. Rework your application to do the network I/O on a background thread (e.g., `AsyncTask`).

Comment: There is such a thing as a Service in the Android framework...android.app.Service, not to mention if he's using AIDLs he could in fact be calling one of the Service's methods.

Comment: @Berdon: " not to mention if he's using AIDLs he could in fact be calling one of the Service's methods" -- eminently possible, which is why I used the word "assume". If my assumption is incorrect, perhaps the OP will clarify.

Comment: "A service is a part of an "app"" I am fairly certain he knows that Service exists. You are coming off somewhat childish in your berating of @commonsware. He speaks the truth network stuff should always be in the background.

Comment: No kidding; my berating is in response to his hasty down voting of my post stating exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

Just a note: making synchronous calls on the UI thread is horrible programming practice for production code - you should **always** make asynchronous call in a background thread and never have to force a psuedo-synchronous call in the manner shown below.

In fact, I'm only posting this because I'm miffed that the API throws an exception when I make a network call using the AndroidHttpClient on the UI thread for brief functional testing before complete implementation. Ie. Testing an operation meant for a background thread without adding frivolous code to make it a background thread when you don't yet need it.

```
final Object lock = new Object();
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        synchronized(lock) {
            // Perform call
            // lock.notify();
        }
    }
}).start();
synchronized(lock) {
    try {
        lock.wait();
    }
    catch{}
}
```

Comment: All this does is get rid of a warning. This code is still broken on all versions of Android, as it will result in slow UI code at best and an ANR dialog at worst, depending on what is done in the background thread.

Comment: Did you READ my note? I specifically state you shouldn't do this - not only that, "This code is still broken..." - orly? Works fine for me on all versions of Android.

Comment: Yes, I read your note. Whatever makes you think that "for testing purposes" somehow makes bad code good? If by "for testing purposes" you mean a JUnit test case, all this means is that your test case will be unreliable (though the degree of unreliability will depend on what you're doing in the thread).

Comment: "Testing purposes" = Implementing any form of code and wanting to make incremental tests of said code without writing the rest of the code, such as testing server API that performs authentication hand-shaking without yet going the distance and adding a DialogFragment in the foreground while a background thread does the rest. Ie. Quick code testing before full-scale implementation. Do you even program?

Comment: @Berden - if your complaint is that the "idiot-proofing" of the API is making quick tests unnecessarily difficult, you could edit your answer to more clearly state that.  Right now, it's not clear who "this is horrible programming practice" applies to - devs who put lengthy operation on the UI thread, or API designers who limit your ability to do risky things for legitimate (as well as illegitimate) reasons.

Comment: @Chris StrattEn - I now see the ambiguity.

Comment: It's better but still has a bit of a disconnect - you start out saying the dev should always be able to do it asynchronously, then seem to complain that you are forced to do so.  Can you find a wording that captures both your opinion of good programming practice and your desire to be able to do otherwise for testing purposes?

Comment: I am complaining the Android team feels the need to hold my hand during development ;)

Comment: I completely understand. There *are* situations where you are bound to using synchronous requests on a background thread (the requests are on a background thread, but are performed synchronously there instead of spinning off additional threads). In these cases, it can be very handy to just throw your synchronous request code into the app to make sure it works before writing the code to attach it to its background thread.